# Understand how backslashes work in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, backslash

I am unable to understand the following results:

```
>>> a='\'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a='\'
        ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal


>>> a=r'\'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a=r'\'
         ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I understood that the prefix 'r' will make the string raw and `\` would be treated as a normal character because `r'\n'` are two characters and I just removed one character from it.

```
>>> a='\\'
>>> a
'\\'
>>> print a
\
>>> repr(a)
"'\\\\'"
```

My understanding: `a='\\'` results in a string which actually contains a single `\` while the other is just used to escape it. Cant understand why `repr(a)` results in so many backslashes.

```
>>> a=r'\\'
>>> a
'\\\\'
>>> print a
\\
>>> repr(a)
"'\\\\\\\\'"
```

My understanding: `a=r'\\'` is a string with two actual `\`s and each of which is prefixed with a `\` to represent it as a python string. Cant understand why simply writing `a` on interpreter returns 4 `\`s and `repr(a)` returns 8 `\`s.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
> ```

The handling for a raw string is performed after the string is lexed. Since `'\'` cannot be lexed validly it cannot be used as part of a raw string.

> ```
> >>> repr(a)
> ```

`repr()` doubles backslashes in the string it returns. Since you are now displaying the representation of a representation the backslashes are quadrupled.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.  prefix 'r' will make the string raw. But '\' is the only exception.

repr 'Return the canonical string representation of the object.'